# the right way to use argparse module in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, argparse

Is that possible to use `argparse` module in JupterNotebook?

For instance, I test the following code segment

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--x', type=int, required=True)
parser.add_argument('--y', type=int, required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
product = args.x * args.y
print('Product:', product)
```

And running the above code in JupterNotebook, I got the following error message

[image]

Comment: There isn't a right way.  `argparse` parses inputs from the commandline.  But the only commandline you use is the one that starts the server.  The `sys.argv` that the notebook sees contains startup values for the kernel, such as a `js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this small code in python:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
parser.add_argument("-v_1", "--verbose_1", help="increase output verbosity",
                    action="store_true")
args = parser.parse_args()
```

To write this code in Jupyter notebook write this:

```
import argparse

args = argparse.Namespace(verbose=False, verbose_1=False)
```

*****Note:***** In python, you can pass arguments on runtime but in the Jupyter notebook that will not be the case so be careful with the data types of your arguments.